# Send BLOB via Post to Java back-end

Tags: java, angular

I recorded a video using recordRTC in my angular project, now I need to send this video via Post to my back end java application.

Here is my angular code:

```
mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev) = > {
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, {
        'type': 'video/mp4;'
    });
    chunks = [];
    let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    vidSave.src = videoURL;
    var file = new File([blob], 'video.mp4', {
        type: 'video/mp4'
    });
}
```

You can see I have the blob Ready to be sent, NOW how I send it via post, please? What's the format?

```
@PostMapping("/recieveAndParseVideo")
public void recieveAndParseVideo( //WHATS the parameter here? form-input? string? blob?) {
    // HOW I RECIEVE THE BLOB HERE?
}
```

Comment: Did you check out https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ and/or https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to send files is using `formData` so in `Angular` use

```
formData = new FormData();
this.formData.append('file', blob);

postMyBlob(formData: any) {
    return this.http.post(`${AppUtils.REST_API_SERVER}/upload-file`, formData);
  }
```

and then in your back

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/upload-file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity<Void> getUploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
            LOGGER.debug(String.valueOf(file));
    }
```